# how to use correctly use pd.Series to load images to list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pd.Series to create a list of images from a folder and relate it to dataset imported from csv file. The created list from pd.Series tends to position the 10th image as the second image and this mistake propagates in the dataset. can anyone help me to correct it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import os.path

image_dir = Path('E:/Notebooks/s2_tiles')
cols = ["labels"]
filepaths = pd.Series(list((image_dir.glob('**\*.tif'))), name='Filepath').astype(str)
labels = pd.read_csv('E:/Notebooks/data.csv', sep=" ", header=None, names=cols)
images = pd.concat([filepaths, labels], axis=1)
```

here is when I print the filepath:

[image]

Comment: Fix your filenames such that they sort naturally. If you have 1000 images, filename 1 should be `0001.tif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do a proper renaming based on the following code:

```
import os
from natsort import natsorted

base_path = r'E:\Notebooks\s2_tiles'
files = natsorted(os.listdir(base_path))


for i, fp in enumerate(files):
    dst = os.path.join(base_path, "{0:04d}.tif".format(i))
    src = os.path.join(base_path, fp) 
    os.rename(src, dst)
```